# Removing delivery step from checkout skips shipping address also in spree + rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

When I write  `remove_checkout_step :delivery` in order_decorator.rb it removes **Shipping Address** info from my `checkout/address` page in spree3-1 stable branch. My requirement is just to skip checkout step 3 page i.e given in image

[image]

Please guide me how to overcome with this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following code to your Rails/Spree app:

In `app/models/spree/order_decorator.rb`

```ruby
Spree::Order.class_eval do
  remove_checkout_step :delivery
end
```